# How to make sure email you send is not automatically marked as spam?

Tags: spam, email-spam

I run a social video website. User's across varied geographic location use this website for e-mailing about the video contents to other people. But my clients report that e-mails they send are automatically marked as spam.I do not want my e-mails marked directed to the spam folder. What can i do to avoid this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: We need to get a honest and real solid answer.  Anyone that works for a large email administrator would be great!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking into sending your emails through Google Apps. You verify with google you own the domain and Google that you own the domain and then you can use google as the outgoing mail server.

Servers can get black-marked for spamming, so if you're on a shared server it could be that your server is on a blacklist. You can know for sure that Google's servers wont be blacklisted..

Google apps is free and easy to setup (I have it on both my sites), if you want to send more than 500emails you have to pay x amount/month, can't remember how much.

Here are some useful links:

1. http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html
2. http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2011/01/google-apps-users-can-now-sign-e-mail-with-dkim.php?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+readwriteweb+(ReadWriteWeb)
3. http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx (see if your server is blacklisted)

Another thing to bear in mind is make sure you have a Privacy Policy (ie what you plan to do with users data) as a lack of Privacy Policy can lead to blocking from some email providers such as Yahoo

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ haroldo: Thanks for your reply. But i cannot afford to use Google apps since my e-mail count is huge. Subscribed services won help my cause. Is there any other way out?

Comment: @ jithin - I'm not sure to be honest. I came across this solution and didn't look much further as I'm not sending tens of thousands of emails. You could look into getting a dedicated server for your outgoing mail and make sure you keep the security on it v. tight. I'm only speculating though I'm afraid